# Do compilers produce better code for do-while loops versus other types of loops?

Tags: c, performance, compiler-construction

There's a comment in the [zlib compression library](http://www.zlib.net/) (which is used in the Chromium project among many others) which implies that a do-while loop in C generates "better" code on most compilers. Here is the snippet of code where it appears.

```
do {
} while (*(ushf*)(scan+=2) == *(ushf*)(match+=2) &&
         *(ushf*)(scan+=2) == *(ushf*)(match+=2) &&
         *(ushf*)(scan+=2) == *(ushf*)(match+=2) &&
         *(ushf*)(scan+=2) == *(ushf*)(match+=2) &&
         scan < strend);
/* The funny "do {}" generates better code on most compilers */
```

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/zlib/deflate.c&l=1225

Is there any evidence that most (or any) compilers would generate better (e.g. more efficient) code?

**Update:** [Mark Adler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Adler), one of the original authors, [gave a bit of context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172402/do-compilers-produce-better-code-for-do-while-loops-versus-other-types-of-loops?noredirect=1#comment30090750_20172402) in the comments.

Comment: By the way, to clarify, this is not part of Chromium. As you can deduce from the URL, this is a "3rd-party" project, and if you look at it even more closely, you can perceive that this code is from ZLib, a widely used, general-purpose compression library.

Comment: `The funny "do {}" generates better code` --- better than what? Than funny while() or than boring, regular do{}?

Comment: @H2CO3 thank you for the clarification, I've edited the question to be more specific about the origin.

Comment: That comment was written more than 18 years ago in the era of Borland and Sun C compilers.  Any relevance to compilers today would be purely accidental.  Note that this particular usage of `do`, as opposed to just a `while` does not avoid a conditional branch.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

First of all:

A `do-while` loop is not the same as a `while`-loop or a `for`-loop.

- `while` and `for` loops may not run the loop body at all.
- A `do-while` loop always runs the loop body at least once - it skips the initial condition check.

So that's the logical difference. That said, not everyone strictly adheres to this. It is quite common for `while` or `for` loops to be used even when it is guaranteed that it will always loop at least once. (Especially in languages with [foreach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop) loops.)

So to avoid comparing apples and oranges, I'll proceed assuming that the loop will always run at least once. Furthermore, I won't mention `for` loops again since they are essentially `while` loops with a bit of syntax sugar for a loop counter.

So I'll be answering the question:

*If a `while` loop is guaranteed to loop at least once, is there any performance gain from using a `do-while` loop instead.*

---

A `do-while` skips the first condition check. So there is one less branch and one less condition to evaluate.

If the condition is expensive to check, and you know you're guaranteed to loop at least once, then a `do-while` loop could be faster.

And while this is considered a micro-optimization at best, it is one that the compiler can't always do: Specifically when the compiler is unable to prove that the loop will always enter at least once.

---

In other words, a while-loop:

```
while (condition){
    body
}
```

Is effectively the same as this:

```
if (condition){
    do{
        body
    }while (condition);
}
```

If you know that you will always loop at least once, that if-statement is extraneous.

---

Likewise at the assembly level, this is roughly how the different loops compile to:

**do-while loop:**

```
start:
    body
    test
    conditional jump to start
```

**while-loop:**

```
    test
    conditional jump to end
start:
    body
    test
    conditional jump to start
end:
```

Note that the condition has been duplicated. An alternate approach is:

```
    unconditional jump to end
start:
    body
end:
    test
    conditional jump to start
```

... which trades away the duplicate code for an additional jump.

Either way, it's still worse than a normal `do-while` loop.

That said, compilers can do what they want. And if they can prove that the loop always enters once, then it has done the work for you.

---

But things are bit weird for the particular example in the question because it has an empty loop body. Since there is no body, there's no logical difference between `while` and `do-while`.

FWIW, I tested this in Visual Studio 2012:

- With the empty body, it does actually generate the same code for `while` and `do-while`. So that part is likely a remnant of the old days when compilers weren't as great.
- But with a non-empty body, VS2012 manages to avoid duplication of the condition code, but still generates an extra conditional jump.

So it's ironic that while the example in the question highlights why a `do-while` loop could be faster in the general case, the example itself doesn't seem to give any benefit on a modern compiler.

Considering how old the comment was, we can only guess at why it would matter. It's very possible that the compilers at the time weren't capable of recognizing that the body was empty. (Or if they did, they didn't use the information.)

Comment: So is checking the condition **one less time** such a great advantage? I highly doubt that. Run the loop 100 times and it becomes entirely insignificant.

Comment: @H2CO3 But what if the loop only runs once or twice? And what about that increased code-size from the duplicated condition code?

Comment: @Mystical If a loop runs only once or twice, then that loop isn't worth optimizing. And the increased code size is... not a solid argument, at best. It's not a requirement that every compiler implement it the way you showed. I have written a [compiler](https://github.com/H2CO3/Sparkling/blob/master/src/compiler.c#L701-L740) for my own toy language, and the compilation of while loops is implemented with an unconditional jump to the beginning of the loop, so code for the condition is only emitted once.

Comment: @H2CO3 "If a loop runs only once or twice, then that loop isn't worth optimizing." - I beg to differ. It could be inside another loop. Tons of my own highly optimized HPC code is like this. And yes the do-while does make a difference.

Comment: @Mystical If it's inside another loop, then that's another question. Also, it's **still** not compulsory for a compiler to implement `while` loops in a certain way... I'm sure there are production compilers which do it differently.

Comment: @H2CO3 Sure. They don't need to compile it that way. But if the compiler can't prove that the loop will always run once, then at minimum an extra jump is needed.

Comment: @Mystical That's true. And again, the relative cost of that one extra jump depends on the context -- and I'm pretty sure most of the time it is not what makes code run slow... But it seems to me that we can't agree on this and SO is already warning me to avoid extended discussions, so here I finish.

Comment: This isn't relevant for the case in question. The condition will be evaluated until it comes out true, regardless of the structure. the "one less" argument only applies when the body modifies something that affects the condition.

Comment: @ugoren True. But that's also a lot of assumptions about the optimizing compiler being able to prove that it's allowed. And as H2CO3 mentions, we don't know how old this is and how capable the compilers at the time were.

Comment: @Mysticial This is not how compilers really do it. At least, not my compilers ;-)

Comment: @EJP Yeah I'm looking at VS2012 output right now. It doesn't match either of ours. :) But the operations counts for jumps and tests are still in the same ballpark.

Comment: @Mysticial Strange. I was writing compilers my way in 1982.

Comment: I think the comment doesn't say that the `do{}while` loop is what produces the "better" code in general, it says *this* specific loop makes better code, i'm guessing that the emphasis is on placing the work in the condition evaluation.

Comment: @Leeor Which comment are you talking about?

Comment: @EJP Probably the one in the code. Which is ironic because in that particular example (with empty body), a modern compiler (VS2012) emits the same code for while and do-while. But in the generic case where there is a body, the do-while is one branch less.

Comment: I guess so. I don't see the point. `while` and `do-while` aren't directly comparable. They do different things. If that's the real code the method calls would totally dominate the extra branch implied by the `while` loop.

Comment: @EJP Aside from the fact that most people just use `while` or `for` even when it's guaranteed to loop at least once. :) It's just a (very) minor micro-optimization missed opportunity. I only see the difference when this is an inner-loop and the iteration count is low and unknown so that it can't be unrolled.

Comment: @Mysticial I don't. I use `while` when I want to loop at least once, and `do-while` when I don't, but it is certainly truer that the use cases for `while` outnumber the use cases for `do-while` by perhaps three or four orders of magnitude, and I might go for years without using `do-while` at all. I'm not prepared to speculate on what 'most people' do. What's the source of your information?

Comment: @EJP My "source" would be the way my colleagues code as well as the source code of our project. There isn't a single `do-while` loop anywhere. Even in places where it is obvious it will always loop once. The point being that if it's not HPC, nobody cares. I even got chastised for using a do-while loop instead of a for-loop because a do-while loop was "less readable" - which I don't entirely disagree with.

Comment: @Mysticial I am a little confused how `while (condition)...` is equivalent to `if(!condition){do{...`. Wouldn't it be `if(condition)`? If the condition was `true` in the first snippet we'd execute the body but we wouldn't even enter the loop in the second snippet.

Comment: @jmathew You're correct. Oversight on my part. I'll fix in a bit. Thanks!

Comment: @Mysticial if even you admit that it's a very slight micro-optimization, then why do you encourage it? that's the wrong behavior, and I'm sad to see that you do this...

Comment: @H2CO3 Where did I say that I was encouraging it? The question asks is a `do-while` loop faster than a while loop. And I answered the question by saying it can be faster. I didn't say by how much. I didn't say whether it was worthwhile. I didn't recommend anybody to start converting to do-while loops. But simply denying that there is a possibility of an optimization, even if it's a small one, is in my opinion a disservice to those who do care and are interested in these things.

Comment: I think someone should look into the "Dragon book" on what code compilers could generate.  Compilers generate while-code basicly like a do-loop with an unconditional jump to the test OR while-code like a do-loop where you have a conditional jump over the initial test. 
No need to generate the test code two times.

Comment: @Anders I doubt modern compilers even have "templates" for compiling loops. They convert everything into a control flow graph and go from there. As for the unconditional jump directly to the loop test, I don't see it often on modern compilers. Usually when the condition is simple, I do actually see the compiler duplicate the condition. My hypothesis in those cases is that an extra test instruction is probably less costly than an unconditional jump.

Comment: And to clarify, you trade the *code-size* of the duplicated code for the extra jump (which must be executed). The number of times you execute the condition is still the same regardless of which version you run. The version that jumps to the condition lets you remove that duplicate code. But you still execute the condition the same # of times - and you also must execute the unconditional jump. So it's one extra instruction to execute. (which might make a difference)

Comment: "That's one less branch and one less condition to evaluate": I disagree with that. Do and while are not interchangeable, it depends on what your semantics is. If you need a loop that executes 0 time or more, while semantics is appropriate; if you need a loop that executes 1 time or more, do semantics pertains. The exact number of tests and branches required dos not depend on the construct but on your program logics.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I believe you might be missing the point of my answer. I'm explicitly addressing the case where the programmer uses `while` or `for` when `do-while` would have sufficed. The micro-optimization being: If you know you will always loop at least once, is there any benefit from converting to `do-while`. In other words, do you "lose" any performance by using `while` or `for` when `do-while` would have been sufficient.

Comment: Yes, but this is not to the credit of the do instruction vs. the while instruction; it is to the credit of the problem itself. This particular string matching problem is a perfect instance of while semantics, because you need to check for empty strings and there can be 0 iterations. It could be implemented here with do semantics because the body is empty and very special (and uncommented) precondition is assumed.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ok. So I addressed both the general case with the non-empty body, and the specific case in the question with the empty body. I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me here.

Answer (score 25):

> Is there any evidence that most (or any) compilers would generate better (e.g. more efficient) code?

Not much, unless you look at the **actual** generated assembly of an **actual, specific compiler** on a **specific platform** with some **specific optimization settings.**

This was probably worth worrying about decades ago (when ZLib has been written), but certainly not nowadays, unless you found, by **real profiling,** that this removes a bottleneck from your code.

Comment: Well put - the phrase `premature optimization` comes to mind here.

Comment: @JamesSnell exactly. And that's what the top rated answer supports/encourages.

Comment: I don't think the top rated answer encourages premature optimization.  I would argue that it shows a difference in efficiency is possible, however slight or insignificant it may be. But people interpret things differently and some may see it as a sign to start using do-while loops when not necessary (I hope not).

Anyway, I'm glad with all of the answers so far. They provide valuable information w.r.t. the question and generated interesting discussion.

Answer (score 16):

**In a nutshell (tl;dr):**

I'm interpreting the comment in OPs' code a little differently, I think the "better code" they claim to have observed was due to moving the actual work into the loop "condition". I completely agree however that it's very compiler specific and that the comparison they made, while being able to produce a slightly different code, is mostly pointless and probably obsolete, as I show below.

---

**Details:**

It's hard to say what the original author meant by his comment about this `do {} while` producing better code, but i'd like to speculate in another direction than what was raised here - we believe that the difference between `do {} while` and `while {}` loops is pretty slim (one less branch as Mystical said), but there's something even "funnier" in this code and that's putting all the work inside this crazy condition, and keeping the internal part empty (`do {}`).

I've tried the following code on gcc 4.8.1 (-O3), and it gives an interesting difference -

```
#include "stdio.h" 
int main (){
    char buf[10];
    char *str = "hello";
    char *src = str, *dst = buf;

    char res;
    do {                            // loop 1
        res = (*dst++ = *src++);
    } while (res);
    printf ("%s\n", buf);

    src = str;
    dst = buf;
    do {                            // loop 2
    } while (*dst++ = *src++);
    printf ("%s\n", buf);

    return 0; 
}
```

After compiling -

```
00000000004003f0 <main>:
  ... 
; loop 1  
  400400:       48 89 ce                mov    %rcx,%rsi
  400403:       48 83 c0 01             add    $0x1,%rax
  400407:       0f b6 50 ff             movzbl 0xffffffffffffffff(%rax),%edx
  40040b:       48 8d 4e 01             lea    0x1(%rsi),%rcx
  40040f:       84 d2                   test   %dl,%dl
  400411:       88 16                   mov    %dl,(%rsi)
  400413:       75 eb                   jne    400400 <main+0x10>
  ...
;loop 2
  400430:       48 83 c0 01             add    $0x1,%rax
  400434:       0f b6 48 ff             movzbl 0xffffffffffffffff(%rax),%ecx
  400438:       48 83 c2 01             add    $0x1,%rdx
  40043c:       84 c9                   test   %cl,%cl
  40043e:       88 4a ff                mov    %cl,0xffffffffffffffff(%rdx)
  400441:       75 ed                   jne    400430 <main+0x40>
  ...
```

So the first loop does 7 instructions while the second does 6, even though they're supposed to do the same work. Now, I can't really tell if there's some compiler smartness behind this, probably not and it's just coincidental but I haven't checked how it interacts with other compiler options this project might be using.

---

On clang 3.3 (-O3) on the other hand, both loops generate this 5 instructions code :

```
  400520:       8a 88 a0 06 40 00       mov    0x4006a0(%rax),%cl
  400526:       88 4c 04 10             mov    %cl,0x10(%rsp,%rax,1)
  40052a:       48 ff c0                inc    %rax
  40052d:       48 83 f8 05             cmp    $0x5,%rax
  400531:       75 ed                   jne    400520 <main+0x20>
```

Which just goes to show that compilers are quite different, and advancing at a far faster rate than some programmer may have anticipated several years ago. It also means that this comment is pretty meaningless and probably there because no one had ever checked if it still makes sense.

---

Bottom line - if you want to optimize to the best possible code (and you know how it should look like), do it directly in assembly and cut the "middle-man" (compiler) from the equation, but take into account that newer compilers and newer HW might make this optimization obsolete. In most cases it's far better to just let the compiler do that level of work for you, and focus on optimizing the big stuff.

Another point that should be made - instruction count (assuming this is what the original OPs' code was after), is by no means a good measurement for code efficiency. Not all instructions were created equal, and some of them (simple reg-to-reg moves for e.g.) are really cheap as they get optimized by the CPU. Other optimization might actually hurt CPU internal optimizations, so eventually only proper benchmarking counts.

Comment: It looks like it saves a register move. `mov %rcx,%rsi` :) I can see how rearranging code can do that.

Comment: @Mystical, you're right about micro optimization though. Sometimes even saving a single instruction isn't worth anything (and reg-to-reg moves should be almost free with reg renaming today).

Comment: It doesn't seem that move renaming was implemented until AMD Bulldozer and Intel Ivy Bridge. That's a surprise!

Comment: @Mysticial, note that these are [roughly](http://www.anandtech.com/show/3922/intels-sandy-bridge-architecture-exposed/3) the first processors implementing a physical register file. Old out-of-order designs just place the register in the reorder buffer, where you can't do that.

Comment: Looks like you interpreted the comment in the original code differently than most, and it makes sense. The comment says "the funny do{}.." but doesn't say to what non-funny version it compares. Most people know the difference between do-while and while, so my guess is that "the funny do{}" didn't apply to that, but to the loop-unrolling and/or the lack of the extra assignment, as you showed here.

Answer (score 10):

A `while` loop is often compiled as a `do-while` loop with an initial branch to the condition, i.e.

```
    bra $1    ; unconditional branch to the condition
$2:
    ; loop body
$1:
    tst <condition> ; the condition
    brt $2    ; branch if condition true
```

whereas the compilation of a `do-while` loop is the same without the initial branch. You can see from that that `while()` is inherently less efficient by the cost of the initial branch, which is however only paid once. [Compare to the naive way of implementing `while,` which requires both a conditional branch and an unconditional branch per iteration.]

Having said that, they aren't really comparable alternatives. It is painful to transform a `while` loop into a `do-while` loop and *vice versa.* They do different things. And in this case the several method calls would totally dominate whatever the compiler did with `while` as against `do-while.`

Answer (score 8):

The remark is not about the choice of the control statement (do vs. while), it is about the loop unrolling !!!

As you can see, this is a string comparison function (string elements probably being 2 bytes long), which could have been written with a single comparison rather than four in a shortcut-and expression.

This latter implementation is for sure faster, as it does a single check of the end-of-string condition after every four element comparisons, whereas standard coding would involve one check per comparison. Said differently, 5 tests per 4 element vs. 8 tests per 4 element.

Anyway, it will work only if the string length is a multiple of four or has a sentinel element (so that the two strings are guaranteed to differ past the `strend` border). Pretty risky !

Comment: That's an interesting observation and something that everyone has overlooked until now. But wouldn't a compiler have no effect on that? In other words, it would always be more efficient regardless of which compiler is used. So then why is there a comment that mentions compilers?

Comment: @Dennis: different compilers have different ways of optimizing generated code. Some may do loop-unrolling themselves (to some extend) or optimize away assignments. Here the coder forces the compiler into the loop-unrolling, making less optimizing compilers perform well still. I think Yves is exactly right about his assumptions, but without the original coder around, it remains a bit of a mystery what the real thought was behind the "funny" remark.

Comment: @Abel thanks for clarifying, I understand the (assumed) meaning behind the comment better now. Yves definitely came closest to solving the mystery behind the comment, but I'm going to accept Mysticial's answer since I think he answered my question best. Turns out I was asking the wrong question because the comment mislead me to focus on the type of loop, while it's probably referring to the condition.

Answer (score 0):

This discussion of while vs. do efficiency is completely pointless in this case, as there is no body.

```
while (Condition)
{
}
```

and

```
do
{
}
while (Condition);
```

are absolutely equivalent.