# Is while faster than for?

Tags: c++, performance, loops, for-loop, while-loop

As in the topic, I learnt in school, that loop `for` is faster than loop `while`, but someone told me that `while` is faster.

I must optimize the program and I want to write `while` instead `for`, but I have a concern that it will be slower?

for example I can change `for` loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
{
   cout<<"dcfvgbh"<<endl;
}
```

into `while` loop:

```
i=0;
while (i<x)
{
    cout<<"dcfvgbh"<<endl;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: you could time it and find out?

Comment: I would be shocked if the assembly produced by both of these was not identical.

Comment: Any question that *can* be asked, *will* be asked.

Comment: I try, but program jams.

Comment: Depends on the compiler implementation of course, but for most compilers, if you compare the assembly code this produces, i strongly suspect that you won't see a difference at all.

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629174/what-loop-is-faster-while-or-for

Comment: The two are obviously equivalent. Any reasonable compiler should generate the same code for both, which you can easily check by looking at the assembly output.

Comment: The first step in optimizing is to learn the name of the language you are programming in. `cout<<` is not C.

Comment: @clcto Well, there might be slight differences in register usage, ordering of code and jumps etc., but essentially it should be the same.

Comment: Under *some* circumstances, [it might be possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172402/do-compilers-produce-better-code-for-do-while-loops-versus-other-types-of-loops) for a `do-while` to be faster than a `while` or `for`. But not between `while` and `for`.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c ;-)

Comment: while loop? When optimizing? Seriously? You obviously have to just manually implement it in assembly and inline it everywhere when you need a loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.**

Nope, it's not.

It is not faster.

Comment: @Mr.Smith sadly you forgot the bold letters in the leading **No.**

Comment: How is this not a good answer? Is it faster? No it's not, and that's a fact.

Answer (score 10):

The standard requires (§6.5.3/1) that:

> The `for` statement
>   for ( for-init-statement condition<sub>opt</sub>; expression<sub>opt</sub>) statement
>   is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>     for-init-statement
>     while ( condition ) {
>         statement
>         expression;
>     }
> }
> ```

As such, you're unlikely to see much difference between them (even if execution time isn't necessarily part of the equivalence specified in the standard). There are a few exceptions listed to the equivalence as well (scopes of names, execution of the expression before evaluating the condition if you execute a `continue`). The latter could, at least theoretically, affect speed a little bit under some conditions, but probably not enough to notice or care about as a rule, and definitely not unless you actually used a `continue` inside the loop.

Answer (score 7):

For all intents and purposes `for` is just a fancy way of writing `while`, so there is no performance advantage either way. The main reason to use one over the other is how the intent is translated so the reader understands better what the loop is actually doing.

Comment: Not for *all* intents and purposes, *continue* keyword has a Small but sometimes critical difference.

Comment: @hyde: Are you saying that using `continue` can be different in a `for` than a `while`?

Comment: To convert a `for` loop which uses `continue` into a `while` loop usually requires changing the logic to not use `continue`: `for(i=0; i<10; ++i) if (i&1) continue; stuff(); if (i&2) continue; stuff2(); }`

Comment: @hyde: `continue` is just a fancy way of writing `goto`. How can it be different either way?

Comment: A central point of your answer seems to be expressing intent when selecting *while* or *for*, so surely you see how *continue* expresses intent inside a loop.

Comment: @hyde: So are you actually just saying that use of `continue` is just one of the factors in deciding whether your intent is better expressed with `for` or `while`? If so, I agree. If you are saying that use of `continue` can have a performance impact, I disagree.

Comment: Oh, no performance impact (or shouldn't be). I just disagree with "For *all* intents and purposes..." part: use of *continue* is the case where the two loops are different, in a way which can bite a programmer refactoring code and converting one to the other, if not aware of the difference.

Comment: By the way, depending on what you do inside the loop, for or while loop might be faster, because not all loops have same contents in them, therefore keywords like continue, goto and in general expressions, such as 2 + 2 can make them slower, check it out: `while(1) {}` is wayyyy faster than `for(int i=0;i; i++) { /* do literally anything at all, for example generate dumb comments like you can see above */}`. TL;DR while and for loop are identical.

Answer (score 3):

You `cout` will eat 99% of the clock cycles for this loop. Beware micro-optimization. At any rate, these two will give essentially identical code.

The only time when a `for` loop can be faster is when you have a known terminating condition - e.g.

```
for(ii = 0; ii < 24; ii++)
```

because some optimizing compilers will perform `loop unrolling`. This means they will not perform a test on every pass through the loop because they can "see" that just doing the thing inside the loop 24 times (or 6 times in blocks of 4, etc) will be a tiny bit more efficient. When the thing inside the loop is very small (e.g. `jj += ii`;), such optimization makes the for loop a bit faster than the `while` (which typically doesn't do "unrolling").

Otherwise - no difference.

**update** at the request of @zeroth

Source: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.47.9346&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Quote from source (my emphasis):

> Unrolling a loop at the source- code level involves identification of
> loop constructs (e.g., for, while, do-while, etc.), determination of
> the loop count to ensure that it is a counting loop, replication of
> the loop body and the adjustment of loop count of the unrolled loop. A
> prologue or epilogue code may also be inserted. Using this approach,
> it is difficult to unroll loops formed using a while and goto
> statements since the loop count is not obvious. However, for all but
> the simplest of loops, this approach is tedious and error prone.
>
> The other alternative is to unroll loops automatically. Automatic
> unrolling can be done early on source code, late on the unoptimized
> intermediate representation, or very late on an optimized
> representation of the program. **If it is done at the source-code level,
> then typically only counting loops formed using for statements are
> unrolled. Unrolling loops formed using other control constructs is
> difficult since the loop count is not obvious.**

Comment: This is very interesting, but I'd like to know more about why while loops are not unrolled when a for loop would be, or which compilers.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge swapping out `for` loops for `while` loops is not an established optimization technique.

Both your examples will be identical in performance, but as an exercise you could time them to confirm this for yourself.