# Which of the control structure take less time complexity?

Tags: c++, algorithm, iteration, time-complexity

In programming, we are using many of the control structure to iterate. So  which one is the best way to iterate with with respect to time complexity?

```
int a[500],n=10;
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
{
cin>>a[i]
}
```

How can I change this iteration achieve less complexity?

Which one is the best way to use for iteration:

1. for
2. while
3. do while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for`, `while` and `do while` (and also `goto`) is really the same thing. No matter what loop you create with one of these loops, you can always create an equivalent loop with the same time complexity with all the others. (Almost true. The only exception is that the do-while loop has to be run at least once.)

For example, your loop

```
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++) {
    ...
}
```

corresponds to

```
int i=0;
while(i<=n) {
    ...
    i++;
}
```

and

```
int i=0;
START:
...
i++;
if(i<=n)
    goto START;
```

You could make an equivalent do-while too, but it does not really make sense.

Which one you should choose is more a matter of design than performance. In general:

- `for` - When you know the number of iterations before the loop starts
- `while` - When you don't know
- `do-while` - When you don't know, but at least once
- `goto` - Never (Some exceptions exists)

A benefit with for loops is that you can declare variables that only exists within the loop scope and also can be used for the loop condition.

Comment: This answer is wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172402/do-compilers-produce-better-code-for-do-while-loops-versus-other-types-of-loops/20172428#20172428

Comment: @user167921 It depends on how you see it. If a loop is run zero times, then it is by definition equivalent to no loop at all, and can thus be replaced with an empty body. I could add a note about it, but do you really think it's that important? After all, this question is about time complexity.

Comment: I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

this will iterate from `i=0` to `i=10`, so 11 iterations in total. The time complexity for any basic loop is O(N).

All the above options mentioned(for-loop, while-loop, do-while-loop) have the same time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

As always, you should use caching techniques for such purposes. Because if you are interested, `for`, `while` keywords in fact do the same thing in almost the same instructions (both are expressed in jmp instruction). Again, silver bullet is not existed. By depending of nature of your program the only way to optimize looping is using caching or parallelization if it can fit yoyr goals. Maybe there is constant values which created only once and used multiple times? Then cache result if it is possible.This can reduce time to 'constant'. Or do it in parallel way. But I think it is not proper way, many things compiler will do for you. Better concentrate on your architecture of program

Answer (score 0):

The use of `for`, `while`, `do-while`, `for-each`, etc could be consider a classic example of [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). They're just ways to do the same thing but in certain cases some control structures can be "sweeter" than others. For instance, if you want to keep iterating iff (if and just if) a boolean keeps `true` (for instance using an Iterator), a `while` look much better than a `for` (well that's a subjective comment), but the complexity will be the same.

```
while (iter.next()) {

// Do something
}

for (;iter.next();) {
// Do something
}
```

In terms of temporal complexity they're iterating the same amount of elements, in your example N=10 therefore O(N). How can you make it better? It depends, if you have to iterate all over the array, the Big O best case will always be O(N). Now in terms of ~N, that statement is not always `true`. For instance if you iterate just half of the array having 2 starting points, one at `i=0` and the other one at `i=n-1`, you can achieve a temporal complexity ~N/2

```
for(int i=0;i<n/2;i++)
{
   int x = a[i];
   int y = a[n-i-1];
   // Do something with those values
}
```

For big O is the same complexity, given that ~N/2 -> O(N) but if you have a set of 10k records, just read 5k is an achievement! In this last case what I'm trying to say is that if you want to improve your code complexity you need to start checking better data structures and algorithms (this is just a simple silly example, there are beautiful algorithms and data structures for multiple cases). Just remember: `for` or `while` are not the big prOblems!